# SSIS Running packages and stored packages folders in 2012 missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

Hi I have installed SSIS 2012 on my system.
I am new to this.
Following this article [Click here](http://sqlserverzest.com/2013/11/04/sql-server-deploying-multiple-ssis-packages-into-sql-server-using-command-prompt-utility-dtutil/)
To see the details.
But in my SSMS (SQL Server Management studio) I do not see such folders as Running Packages and Stored Packages .
Are they removed in SSIS 2012 ?
I know about Package deployment model and Project deployment model which is available in SSIS 2012.
But I am just curious as the folders I am talking about are really removed or is it the defect that my system has ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when you're on the Connect window that you are choosing Integration Services in the Server Type dropdown. https://schmittdotnet.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/image.png

Comment: Thanks for your comment